# getting KeyError on certain residues in BioPython: ATOM vs. HETATM lines

Tags: python, pdb

When I want to load atoms for residuum `(' ', 85, ' ')` in chain *A* for protein **3tmm** with `structure[0][chain_id][residue]`, but I'm getting `KeyError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/home/pok/Checkouts/bilkoviny/loader.py", line 118, in _get_residue_atoms
    return list(self.structure[0][chain_id][residue])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Chain.py", line 74, in __getitem__
    return Entity.__getitem__(self, id)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    return self.child_dict[id]
KeyError: (' ', 85, ' ')
```

I assume this is because this residuum do not have "ATOM" lines in PDB file:

```
[...]
ATOM    704  CD1 ILE A  84      19.348  -4.839  18.138  1.00 47.08           C  
ANISOU  704  CD1 ILE A  84     5862   6108   5917   -216  -1513    609       C  
HETATM  705  N   MSE A  85      21.619  -0.130  16.236  1.00 31.89           N  
ANISOU  705  N   MSE A  85     5143   3072   3900   -766  -1011    962       N  
HETATM  706  CA  MSE A  85      22.277   0.675  15.226  1.00 40.76           C  
ANISOU  706  CA  MSE A  85     6708   3869   4911   -972   -729   1162       C  
HETATM  707  C   MSE A  85      23.146   1.786  15.818  1.00 44.98           C  
ANISOU  707  C   MSE A  85     7191   4141   5757  -1268   -558   1109       C  
HETATM  708  O   MSE A  85      24.257   2.045  15.338  1.00 43.69           O  
ANISOU  708  O   MSE A  85     7055   3855   5692  -1611   -151   1153       O  
HETATM  709  CB  MSE A  85      21.244   1.265  14.269  1.00 46.50           C  
ANISOU  709  CB  MSE A  85     8043   4309   5316   -709   -948   1345       C  
HETATM  710  CG  MSE A  85      21.849   1.954  13.052  1.00 54.03           C  
ANISOU  710  CG  MSE A  85     9604   4929   5995   -907   -623   1638       C  
HETATM  711 SE   MSE A  85      20.503   2.755  11.877  1.00 84.35          SE  
ANISOU  711 SE   MSE A  85    14348   8336   9366   -486  -1038   1884      SE  
HETATM  712  CE  MSE A  85      21.690   3.538  10.518  1.00 83.79           C  
ANISOU  712  CE  MSE A  85    15063   7865   8907   -915   -414   2326       C  
ATOM    713  N   SER A  86      22.636   2.453  16.846  1.00 43.76           N  
ANISOU  713  N   SER A  86     5234   6599   4794  -1778   -946    195       N  
[...]
```

I have been told "MSE is same as MET, it is just with selenium instead of sulphur" and that I probably need to load these atoms (I'm approximating secondary structure element position, so I want individual atom coordinates).

Is there some way how to get atoms for this residue in this protein via BioPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in [The Biopython Structural Bioinformatics FAQ](http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ):

> **What is a residue id?**
>
> This is a bit more complicated, due to the clumsy PDB format. A
> residue id is a tuple with three elements:
>
> - The **hetero-flag**: this is 'H_' plus the name of the hetero-residue (e.g. 'H_GLC' in the case of a glucose molecule), or 'W' in the case
>   of a water molecule.
> - The **sequence identifier** in the chain, e.g. 100
> - The **insertion code**, e.g. 'A'. The insertion code is sometimes
>   used to preserve a certain desirable residue numbering scheme. A Ser 80
>   insertion mutant (inserted e.g. between a Thr 80 and an Asn 81
>   residue) could e.g. have sequence identifiers and insertion codes as
>   follows: Thr 80 A, Ser 80 B, Asn 81. In this way the residue numbering
>   scheme stays in tune with that of the wild type structure.
>
> The id of the above glucose residue would thus be ('H_GLC', 100, 'A').

So in your case it would be `('H_MSE', 85, ' ')`.

Comment: Thank you! Please do you know if there is a way how to get something like `(*, 85, *)` - I mean, if I do not care about hetero-flag and insertion code at all.

Comment: @jhutar ignoring biopython hetero-flag would make sense, as it is biopython-specific workaround for incorrect PDB files; I don't know if it's possible. Do not ignore insertion codes, they are part of the sequence number.